# classpath:conf. Where is this pointing too in my IntelliJ Groovy project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, redis, classpath

I have a bit of code that is searching the file path for a configuration file. 
it is inside the RedisCacheUtil file, for a Redisson Cache project created by https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis.

I am not understanding where to put this configuration file so that it can be found and read  in code. It is failing to load the properties file, and subsequent property files and properties because of this, and causing a crash. StackTrace and logs below. 
[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
at org.hibernate.cache.redis.util.RedisCacheUtil.loadCacheProperties(RedisCacheUtil.java:68)
at org.hibernate.cache.redis.hibernate52.SingletonRedisRegionFactory.start(SingletonRedisRegionFactory.java:54)
at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:49)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:241)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
```

Comment: [Resources directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)?

Comment: I believe i figured it out but I'm seeing another problem. 
regarding the one above. There was a property set in the Application.yaml file, set improperly, so it was checking a default fall-back path. Once I set the property in the yaml correctly it looked where i wanted it to look